# Jenkins plugin details

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In the Jenkins about page (`Manage Jenkins > About Jenkins`) I can see the list of plugins installed (under `License and dependency information for plugins` section). However I noticed few plugin names are striked through.

Is it because of any version conflict? It does not show any detail as to what needs to be done to fix this. Any pointers please?

Comment: Interesting question. I checked mine and only have HTML Audio Notifier striked out... that happens to be last updated in 2012

Comment: Which version of Jenkins are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `License and dependency information for plugins` section is populated from the plugins you installed via $JENKINS_URL/pluginManager.

Taken directly from [Jenkins's source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/hudson/AboutJenkins/index.jelly), as of `606794a on 15 May 2016`:

```
<h2>${%plugin.dependencies}</h2>
      <ul>
        <j:forEach var="p" items="${app.pluginManager.plugins}"> <!-- TODO sort -->
        <li>
          <a href="${rootURL}/pluginManager/plugin/${p.shortName}/thirdPartyLicenses">
      <j:choose>
        <j:when test="${p.active}">
          ${p.displayName}
        </j:when>
        <j:otherwise>
          <strike>${p.displayName}</strike>
        </j:otherwise>
      </j:choose>
    </a>
  </li>
  </j:forEach>
</ul>
```

The plugin will be striked through if it is inactive. Inactive simply means it's disabled, but not deleted.

Plugins can be manually disabled via the UI or automatically after an update if there is an issue such as compatibility.